# Вирізають апендикс чи апендицит?

Tags: вибір-слова

Часто люди вживають вираз "...вирізали *апендицит*". Перевіривши в словнику виявила, що [апендицитом](http://sum.in.ua/s/apendycyt) називається саме захворювання, а орган, що вирізають під час операції, називають [апендиксом](http://sum.in.ua/s/apendyks). Чи це специфіка медичних термінів? Як все-таки правильно сказати "вирізали *апендицит*" чи "вирізали *апендикс*"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Щодо підтвердження Ваших думок про сплутування термінів, натрапила також на статтю у [Віснику здоров’я](http://vashaibolit.com.ua/299-apendiks-apendicit.html):

> Як не дивно, але в розумінні багатьох людей терміни «апендикс» і «апендицит» є абсолютно рівними за своїм значенням. У народі часто можна почути ріжучі слух будь-якого лікаря або біолога вислови про те, як болить апендицит або про те, що хтось переніс апендикс.
>
> Слід чітко розмежовувати ці терміни. **Апендикс - це назва органу**. А термін **«апендицит»** використовують для позначення **патологічного стану**, при якому спостерігається запалення червоподібного відростка. В результаті в порожнині органу відзначається посилений розвиток мікроорганізмів, що, в свою чергу, обумовлює запалення слизової оболонки червоподібного відростка, порушується пересування крові по судинах в цій ділянці тіла і призводить до відмирання клітин та тканин.

Знайшла також і ще одне джерело: [Уроки української мови](http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/11.htm), де йдеться про ці терміни і їх розмежування:

> **Апендикс і апендицит**. Перше слово означає “червоподібний відросток сліпої кишки людини та деяких хребетних тварин,” друге — “запалення апендикса”. Тому не слід казати і писати: вирізали апендицит, хворіє апендицитом. Адже насправді вирізують (видаляють) апендикс, а хворіють на апендицит.

Дозволю і собі висловити власні міркування.

Не можна ж виразати хворобу, тому вирізають орган - апендикс. Ймовірно, людям озвучили, що діагноз "апендицит" і вилікуватись потрібнно шляхом хірургічного втручання, тобто вирізання. Можливо, звідти пішло і саме сплутування понять.

Comment: Додам список хвороб і органів дихання для ілюстрації: трахеїт - запалення трахеї, бронхіт - запалення бронхів.